# UNITY - How do I change color at a delay?

Tags: unity-game-engine, delay

I am trying to change the background color of the Main Camera. When I put the code below, it changes the color every frame. Why does this happen? How can I fix it?

```
function Update () {
ChangeColor();
}

function ChangeColor() {
this.camera.backgroundColor = Color32(Random.Range(0, 255), Random.Range(0, 255), Random.Range(0, 255), 1);
yield WaitForSeconds(5);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for something called [Coroutines](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Coroutine.html]).

`Update()` is called 60 times per second. As you have `ChangeColor()` inside the `Update()` method, it will be called regardless of the yield statement within the `ChangeColor()` method, as yield only works from inside coroutines.

You will need to call the method like this:

```
StartCoroutine(ChangeColor());
```

or

```
StartCoroutine("ChangeColor");
```

Be aware that if you put that line inside the `Update()` method you will be starting a new coroutine 60 times a second. If you want `ChangeColor()` to continually run after being started you'll need to change its logic slightly and place it in your `Start()` method, or in a place where it's called once.

```
    function ChangeColor() {
    while(true){
        this.camera.backgroundColor = Color32(Random.Range(0, 255), Random.Range(0, 255),     Random.Range(0, 255), 1);
        yield WaitForSeconds(5);
        }
    }
```

You'll notice I added a while loop that is an infinite loop, and INSIDE the while loop I placed the yield statement. This will properly yield the method for 5 seconds before looping again and yielding forever.

Some additional notes:

- Make sure you choose the correct version of `StartCoroutine(...)`. The one that takes a string can be stopped by using `StopCoroutine("NameOfMethod")`. The other one that takes the method signature itself cannot be stopped after being started.
- Coroutines live on the gameobject script that creates them. So if your camera had the script which calls the `ChangeColor()` method and it was destroyed, then the `ChangeColor()` coroutine is also stopped and destroyed.

Links to the other coroutine methods.

[StartCoroutine](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html)

Comment: Also a word of warning. Do not confuse coroutines with multi-threading. Coroutines will run during the main Unity loop.http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html